# Schock absorbers misting

Tags: suspension, audi, shock-absorber, a3

My car has a schock absorbers misting report on a test
Audi a3 built 2009
Now my question  is could this case a bumpy ride I.e when the car rides of bumpy road,  the drive feels very rough 
Best regards

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What do you mean by "misting"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this could well be the cause of your issues with the ride quality - if the shocks are "misting" that means they are losing oil (although not at a huge rate) and as the shock absorber's oil level goes down so does their damping performance.

It might not be the *only* factor causing it - there's likely to be wear to other suspension components as well but it's certainly a big factor.